# Mandrill Forward a friend and Unsubscribe

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

Full Request in sending mail.

{
    "message": {
        "subject": "Test message",
        "from_email": "",
        "html": "

this is a test message with Mandrill's PHP wrapper!.Unsubscribe | Forward A friend

",
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "*****",
                "name": "Recipient 1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "async": false,
    "ip_pool": "",
    "send_at": "",
    "key": "*****" // API KEY
}
Full Response
[
    {
        "email": "*****",
        "status": "sent",
        "_id": "****************",
        "reject_reason": null
    }
]

Getting the mail but Unsubscribe and Forward A friend not work in mail.
I am using the mandrill API.

Please guided me.

Answer (score 0):

Those merge tags are specific to MailChimp and won't work by default in Mandrill. More info can be found in the Mandrill KB: [Can I use MailChimp merge tags in Mandrill emails?](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/28524968-Can-I-use-MailChimp-merge-tags-in-Mandrill-emails-)

Comment: You mean say forward a friend not directly use in mandrill mail. *|UNSUB:http://mywebsite.com/unsub|* - its working but redirect to own page. Any other method to implement forward a friend in mandrill mail.